# Dell XPS 15 hard drive wont stop spinning

Tags: dell-xps

My XPS 15 is very noisy; it seems like I can always hear the head spinning (that low-pitched gurgling sound like the computer is running - I think it's the hard drive).  Is this normal?

Comment: No; I am guessing it wasn't always this noisy, you should replace the hdd immediately

Answer (score 0):

Not normal for a HDD to be cranking away non-stop in a laptop, unless you're constantly writing to it, but you'd be aware of that. Are you certain its the disk?
I find that lots of laptops become noisy due to dust/debris forming on the fans. This also results in overheating eventually.

In Win7 you can run the resource monitor to view your HDD use in a live graph, in Win 8 & 10 this is integrated into the task manager. If youre seeing high constant activity there it confirms HDD use to investigate further, if no activity it might just need a thorough cleaning. 
edit: resource monitor can be utilized in 8 or 10 as well and is a good means of finding what process, if anything, is writing to the disk constantly